# Passing JSONObject/JSONArray from AsyncTask to UI Thread

Tags: java, android, json

I've seen people post a Toast or something like that to the UI thread from the onProgressUpdate()/onPostExecute() methods, but I'd like to do something where I can pass a JSONObject or a JSONArray back to the UI thread.

In my AsyncTask, I'm calling a webservice, which returns a JSONObject or JSONArray and I want to take that and display it in a page fragment on the UI thread.

Does anyone know how I can do this, or can point me to a tutorial that can show me?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you can return the `JSONObject` from `doInBackground` method and receive/handle that object on `onPostExecute`. In `onPostExecute`, you can access the UI Thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation, you will see that you can actually pass pretty much everything to `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate`:

```
private class JsonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, String, JSONObject> {

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         // usrls to connect to server
         publishProgress(/* some string you got, for example */
         // ...
         return /* a json object you created from data received */;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(String ... progress) {
         // parse the string and display it
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
         // display results from the JSONObject
     }
 }
```

The example below can be changed to any other parameters, where the generic types are ordered like that:

1. The first is the type received by `doInBackground`.
2. The second is the type passed to `publishProgress` and received by `onProgressUpdate`.
3. The third is the return type from `doInBackground` and received by `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a listener to your async task and call it onPostExecute

```
public interface MyListener {
  public abstract void onResult(Object json);
}

MyTask mt = new MyTask(new MyListener() {
  public void onResult(Object json) {
    //catch your object here
  }
});
mt.execute();

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> {

  private MyListener listener;

  public MyTask(MyListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    if (listener != null) {
      listener.onResult(result);
    }
  }

  protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Object result = new Object();
    //your task
    return result;
  }

}
```